# CentOS Server Name does not work

Tags: django, networking, nginx, gunicorn, centos6

I'm using CentOS 6.5 with hostname `NAFD` only together with ip an address `192.9.200.69`. I successfully installed Django-NginX-Gunicorn with Supervisor using this [tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/).

The django run successfully in `127.0.0.1:8000` without errors. I have no problem accessing the webserver django admin within the root user or other user within CentOS. With the assumption that django webserver should be accessable within the network, I can move on now to the next stage testing the application from client computer.

Here's the problem start.

When I try using `http://nafd:8000/admin` to connect from client computer within the network it gave me `page not found`. But when I used `http://192.9.200.69/admin` I get Nginx Welcome Powered Page.

I already set the CentOS firewall to accept port from 80 and 8000. I can ping the webserver using its ip address.

This is the first time I used Nginx-Gunicorn with Supervisor. I'm been using Django only in Win7 without giving me a problem accessing the webserver from client side.

From reading other related problems and possible solutions my direction now is installing DNS Server in my CentOS 6.5.

I need help if this is the right track to do? Or is there other possible way to solve this.

Thank you for your time reading.

**Trace Route Result:**

```
C:\Windows\System32>tracert -4 192.9.200.69

Tracing route to 192.9.200.69 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.9.200.69

Trace complete.
```

**NGINX Config**

```
server {
  server_name nafd;
  access_log off;

  location /static/ {
       alias /opt/nafd/nafd_proj/nafd_proj/static;

  }

  location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
       proxy_set_header X-Forward-Host $server_name;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
  }
```

}

**Gunicorn Config**

```
command = '/opt/nafd/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/opt/nafd/nafd_proj'
bind = '127.0.0.1:80'
workers = 3
#user = 'nafdit'
```

**Update**

When I run django in `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`, I can access the application from any computer within the network using `192.9.200.69:8001/admin` in url but `nafd:8001/admin` don't work remotely.

Comment: Ping is just not enough to test if dns is working fine. Run a traceroute. and also share you nginx and gunicorn configs.

Comment: What is "127.0.0.0:8000" supposed to be? I'm guessing it should either be 0.0.0.0 for all ip addresses or 127.0.0.1 for local access only.

Comment: @Danack, I stand corrected..it should be 0.0.0.0..@Anup, my config is almost the same as the tutorial. I' ll post my complete config later together with the trace route result

Comment: I completely disable my Firewall and SELINUX..but still the problem persist

Comment: do you follow tutorial and launch your applications with `bin/gunicorn_start` script?

Comment: I found a tutorial that I can add `"gunicorn"` in installed app under `setup.py` and running `python manage.py run_gunicorn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a DNS problem, your remote computer cannot resolve `nafd` to `192.9.200.69`. You can check this by running `nslookup 192.9.200.69`, you probably will not get `nafd`. As a quick check you can change the remote computer's [`hosts` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and add `192.9.200.69 nafd` at the end, this will hardcode the host name to that IP address. Then restart your browser and try accessing `nafd:8001/admin`.

This will only make it work in **that particular computer**, for it to work across all computers in your network you'll need to set up a DNS server for your network (try [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-the-bind-dns-server-on-centos-6) [tutorials](http://www.unixmen.com/dns-server-installation-step-by-step-using-centos-6-3/))

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this the difference between working in development mode and in production mode..by setting up DNS Server?

Comment: No, you're just having a network problem, even if you had a production server running on a different port your remote computer would not be able to access it. That being said you should strongly consider moving to a production server anyway: from the [runserver doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port): *DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests.*

Comment: Checking the Bind DNS to CentOS, do hostname `NAFD` is enough as a name for the server name or do I need to create a dummy domain name maybe like a word `local`. with a final hostname like `NAFD.local`?

Comment: Im trying to install DNS SERVER on the computer where I setup my webserver without virtualization..and still I cant access the url nafd.local:8000/admin. I' ll try this coming monday to install DNS SERVER  in a diferrent computer.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it here are 3 possible solutions.

**DNS** or Domain Name Service (or some call it domain name server). The DNS system usually just translates domain name / host names to ip addresses, and depending on your network set up, this may be a bit overkill. Mostly if you don't have a dedicated DNS server and are using an ISR or something of the like where you can't manually add a DNS, this would require quite a bit of network reconfiguration.

**Netbios/WINS** name. Windows by default will attempt communication using WINS/netbios names, however WINS being "Windows Internet Name Service" is not a feature that usually comes with most linux distros. To get this set up, you will need to install Samba and get it set up and opening the needed ports. http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba may help you out with this.

**Hosts file** configuration. It is also possible to get the functionality that you want by manually editing the hosts file of each computer. This would be like putting a manual DNS entry in each computer, and would also require that you make this configuration change for each computer you ever wish to add to the network (if you want to be able to browse by the PC name). in windows 7 the hosts file is located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and you would add the line "192.9.200.69 NAFD" to the bottom of the file. You should be able to use notepad, but you may wnat to note, notepad would have to be opened with Admin rights as it is a system file.

Of these 3 options, the one that sounds most like what you want with the least effort, would be setting up the samba service (Netbios/WINS) on the CentOS box.

Comment: Linx, very helpful links..I'll try your approach. Samba style..sounds like Zumba Dance :)

Comment: Linx, If I install Samba..Is this means I don't need to install DNS Server on a seperate computer, since I'm using Web Server and DNS Server on the same computer...just a thought

Comment: @Charlesliam If you install samba then you will not need to set up fancy DNS.